# ¿Cómo obtener los últimos tres resultados de una sucesión numérica con su respectiva identificación en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Al ingresar el valor 5, este me mostrará la siguiente información como resultado:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8
```

Si ingreso el valor 6, mostrará lo siguiente:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
```

Ahora lo que necesito es saber cómo obtener los últimos tres resultados de una sucesión numérica es decir tomado como ejemplo, el primer caso:

```
el primero: 3
el segundo: 5
y el último es: 8
```

En el segundo caso:

```
El primero: 5
el segundo: 8
y el último valor es: `13`
```

Este es mi código:

```
public class PracticaTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n,ultimonumero,primero,segundo,i;
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Ingrese un número mayor o igual a 1: ");
            n = lector.nextInt();
        }while(n<=0);
        System.out.print("Los " + n + " primeros términos de la serie: ");

        primero=0;
        segundo=1;

        System.out.print(primero + " ");
        for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
            System.out.print(segundo + " ");
            segundo = primero + segundo;
            primero = segundo - primero;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

> **Nota:** Estoy usando el **IDE NetBeans** y, ya tengo definida una variable llamada `ultimonumero` que es donde deseo almacenar dicha información y, en conjunto con las variables `primero` y, `segundo` se debe identificar la información.

---

Resultado esperado:

Los 5 primeros términos de la serie:    0 1 1 2 3 5 8

Primero: 3 Segundo: 5 ultimonumero: 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es que tienes oportunidad de agregar nuevas variables podrías hacerlo de esta manera, 
 la variable ultimoNumero solo lo igualas a la variable segundo al final del ciclo for

```
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        System.out.print(segundo + " ");
        If(i == n){
            auxiliar1 = segundo - primero;
            auxiliar2 = primero;
            ultimoNumero = segundo;
        }
        segundo = primero + segundo;
        primero = segundo - primero;
    }
```

Comment: Hola @Leon gracias por responder, me dí cuenta que tengo un error en la identificación y, actualice mi pregunta justo casi al instante de su respuesta :( crees poder ayudarme.

Comment: Te refieres a que deseas saber el último número de la sucesión y el número de iteración en el que se dio? por ejemplo el último número fue 5, en la iteración 4. No entiendo la parte de su "respectiva identificación en Java"

Comment: Si, la serie de Fibonacci si la conozco, a lo que me refiero es que cual es el resultado que esperas, podrías poner un ejemplo de la impresión que esperas

Comment: Listo amigo, he actualizado mi pregunta agregado al final el resultado esperado.

Comment: Hice una edición en la cuál podrías llegar a tu resultado deseado, con una condición y dos variables nuevas

Comment: puedes ayudar agregando el código completo, porque la `IDE NetBeans` me exige que inicialice la variable `ultimonumero` y, si le inicializo con un valor de `0` este me imprime el resultado del valor inicializado, no comprendo como inicializarla sin que suceda eso, esto solo me sucede en el caso de la variable `ultimonumero` ahora que sucederá con las nuevas variables auxiliares.

Comment: Cierto pues, solo inicializalas en 0 cuando declaras las variables al principio int ultimonumero = 0, auxiliar1 = 0, auxiliar2 = 0; pero no debería tener problemas ya que le estás asignando un nuevo valor en el ciclo for.  Por ahora estoy en celular se me hace difícil poner todo el código

Comment: listo ya lo solucione con la inicialización de variables, pero lo que si tengo un problema con esta variable amigo `auxiliar2 = auxiliar1 + primero;` me imprime el último número y, no el segundo número.

Comment: Cierto ya lo cambie

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, estoy iniciando en Java pero creo que no voy muy mal :)